# Unable to change to german language

Tags: administration

I already have german selected as my orgs language settings. However when i am changing the language settings inside Personal information to german the objects name remain the same in English.

Comment: Object names won't be translated automatically. You need [translation workbench](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=entering_translated_terms.htm) for this

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to - **/ui/setup/RenameTabPage** 
Select Language as 'German' to the top and click on edit for individual custom objects to the bottom.